# Reading the dictionary element values

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

> I have the below code where I want to read the value of dictionary 'filter' using for loop.'filter[1]'again has two values. Since dictionary is key value pair, how do I access the element value below.

```
class program
{
public string RecSys { get; set; }
public string AnsSys { get; set; }
public string IsAddOn { get; set; }
public string Country { get; set; }

public static void Main()
{
    program p1 = new program();
    program p2 = new program();
    program p3 = new program();
    List<program> List = new List<program>();

    p1.RecSys = "RY1";
    p1.AnsSys = "CSCLRC";
    p1.IsAddOn = "P";
    p1.Country = "India";
    List.Add(p1);

    p2.RecSys = "RY1";
    p2.AnsSys = "APEX";
    p2.IsAddOn = "primary";
    p2.Country = "Pakistan";
    List.Add(p2);

    p3.RecSys = "RY1";
    p3.AnsSys = "APEX";
    p3.IsAddOn = "Addon";
    p3.Country = "Pakistan";
    List.Add(p3);

    var filter = List.GroupBy(item => new { item.RecSys, item.AnsSys }).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList()).Values;

    for (int i = 0; i < filter.Count; i++)
    {
        // read the values. 'filter[1]'again has two values 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Wondering why you create a `Dictionary` and then use just `Values`

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the values using two `foreach` loop like this:-

```
foreach (var item in filter)
{
    foreach (var innerItem in item)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(innerItem.IsAddOn);
         Console.WriteLine(innerItem.Country);
         //and so on..
    }
}
```

Or else if you want all the `Values` of dictionary at once then you can flatten it using [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
var filter = List.GroupBy(item => new { item.RecSys, item.AnsSys })
                 .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList())
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Value);
```

and finally iterate over the items using a single `foreach` loop:-

```
foreach (var item in filter)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Country);
    Console.WriteLine(item.AnsSys);
    //and so on..
}
```

Comment: Isn't the result of your second example (with `SelectMany`) producing basically the original list. And `ToDictionary` being totally redundant.

Comment: @IvanStoev - That depends on OP, he might be posting just the sample data that's why I mentioned _if you want all the Values of dictionary at once_.

Comment: @Rahul Singh In the second foreach can we order by IsAddon?

Comment: You can do it directly in the query itself but after @Ivan Stoev's comment I also got confused why you are projecting a dictionary and then fetching Values? What is the expected output?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a sample data or not. The whole OP make no sense, since `GroupBy` followed by `SelectMany` just produces the original sequence, only with different order, so most probably he just needs `OrderBy`. Just thought.

Comment: for combination of (RY1, APEX) there are two values. 1. RY1, APEX, primary 2.RY1, APEX, Addon. I just want to loop with 'primary' first

Comment: @GirishKumar - Didn't get you? What you are trying to do within that group?

Comment: @RahulSingh just the o/p of---  foreach (var item in filter)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in item)
            {
                if (item.Count > 1)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(item2.IsAddOn);
                    Console.WriteLine(item2.Country); 
                }
                //and so on..
            }
        }

Comment: print Addon first then primary

Comment: @GirishKumar - I am still not clear what you are trying to do but you can write a OrderBy in your second foreach like this: `foreach (var item2 in item.OrderBy(x => x.IsAddOn))`

Comment: @RahulSingh Again I just want to filter the second loop as
foreach (var item1 in item.OrderBy(x => x.IsAddOnProfile).Where(Count((x => x.IsAddOnProfile) > 1))

Comment: @GirishKumar - I am asking you again and again what is your expected output. You should not do all these inside `foreach` that is just for retrieval of data.

Comment: Just see this collection. Paste on notepad.

 RY1 CSCLRC P        INDIA

                              Primary  
 RY1 APEXP  primary  Pakistan
                              Addon